# MATLAB - Add Value at the first column of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to add one value at the beginning of a matrix for  example, my matrix is

```
0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0
1,0,0,1,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0
```

then I want to add '1' or '0' at the first column therefore it will become like this

```
1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,1,1,0,0
1,1,0,0,1,0,0
1,1,1,1,0,0,0

0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,1,0,0
0,1,0,0,1,0,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

how can I do that in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can concatenate matrices without creating another one from scratch like this:

```
% your matrix
A = [ 0,0,0,0,0,0;
      0,1,1,1,0,0;
      1,0,0,1,0,0;
      1,1,1,0,0,0 ];

A_with_zeros = [zeros(size(A,1),1) A]
A_with_ones = [ones(size(A,1),1) A]

% Output:
%  A_with_zeros = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
%                   0 0 1 1 1 0 0
%                   0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
%                   0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
% 
%  A_with_ones = [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
%                  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
%                  1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
%                  1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ]
```

**Documentation about concatenating matrices**:

[horzcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/horzcat.html)

[vertcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html)

These two documentation pages describe in details the existing methods that let you concatenate arrays horizontally (what I did in the example above) and vertically (if you wanted to add lines to your matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Use the array concatenation syntax - `[a b]` to glue matrices together horizontally, `[a; b]` to glue them together vertically.

Like so:

```
>> a = ones(3,1)

a =

     1
     1
     1

>> b = magic(3)

b =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> c = [a b]

c =

     1     8     1     6
     1     3     5     7
     1     4     9     2
```

Vertically:

```
>> d = ones(1,3)

d =

     1     1     1

>> e = [d; b]

e =

     1     1     1
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

If you mismatch the dimensions, MATLAB will give you an error. Don't do this:

```
>> f = ones(1,10)

f =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

>> g = magic(3)

g =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2

>> [f; g]
??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new matrix with an extra column, copy the old matrix in, then put the data for the new column in at (:, 1).

```
output = zeros(size(input, 1), size(input, 2) + 1);
output(:, 2:end) = input;
output(:, 1) = new_column;
```

or if you mean that you want to get two matricies, one with a column of 1s and one with a column of 0s:

```
output0 = zeros(size(input, 1), size(input, 2) + 1);
output0(:, 2:end) = input;
output1 = ones(size(input, 1), size(input, 2) + 1);
output1(:, 2:end) = input;
```